# Rsync detect if transfer on same filesystem

Tags: bash, rsync

I want to alias the `mv` command to `rsync -av --progress --remove-source-files` to make the mv command more verbose.

It works, but can I add a way to detect if I'm moving the file within the same filesystem to just do the normal `mv` command instead, so that it doesn't copy then remove?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the filesystem identifier for source and destination

```
stat -f -c %i /path/to/file
```

I don't think there's any way this can be squeezed into an alias, but it wouldn't be too hard to write a simple script, and if you really wanted you could alias `mv` to that script

Put this into a file (for example named `mvrsync`) somewhere in your `PATH`, make it executable (`chmod a+x /path/to/mvrsync`)

```
#!/bin/bash
#
args=("$@")                                      # In this example we do not consider -flags
[[ -t 2 ]] && vp=-vP                             # Only make rsync noisy if we're on a terminal

dst="${args[-1]}"; unset args[-1]                # Single destination

dstX="$dst" dstFS=
[[ "${dstX:0:1}" != / ]] && dstX="$PWD/$dstX"    # Absolute path
while [[ -z "$dstFS" ]]; do
    dstFS=$(stat -f -c %i "$dst" 2>/dev/null)    # Look for a target that exists
    dstX="${dstX%/*}"                            # Prepare to try again with parent
done

for src in "${args[@]}"                          # Everything else must be a source
do
    # See if src and dst are on same filesystem
    srcFS=$(stat -f -c %i "$src")                # Could pre-check for file existence
    if [[ "$srcFS" == "$dstFS" ]]
    then
        # Same filesystem, use mv directly
        mv -f "$src" "$dst"
    else
        # Different filesystem
        rsync -aAXX $vp --remove-source-files "$src" "$dst"
    fi
done
```

Mind you, having written this I'm not sure why you'd want to use `rsync` in this situation as it only can only act like a slow version of `cp && rm` or even your friend `mv`

Comment: stat -f returns different IDs if 2 systems mounts the same lustre filesystem. So in that case, you can't rely on stat -f IDs. I can't think of any other way other than creating a random file on 1 system, then try to find that file on another system to see if they are indeed pointing to the same filesystem...